# MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT GOT AN ERROR IN MORE THAN 2 TABLES

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Hi i need to fetch the product information from the backend .. 
I have a 
productTable
productInformation
productAttributes
productCategories
productImages

My database query is ,

```
select
    p.id,
    p.name as entityName,
    pi.name,
    pi.description,
    pi.language,
    GROUP_CONCAT(im.image SEPARATOR ';') as images,
    ci.name as categoryname
from products p,
    productInformation pi,
    product_attributes pa,
    images im,
    categoryInformation ci,
    categories c
where
    ci.category=c.id and
    ci.language='en' and
    c.id = p.category and
    p.category in (1,2) and
    im.entityid=p.id and
    im.type='product' and
    pi.language='en' and
    pi.productid=p.id and
    pa.attributevalueid in (2) and
    p.id=pa.productid and
    p.name like '%p%' and
    p.price between 0 and 15  ;
```

The query was working fine before , 
After i added the GROUP_CONCAT in the query

There is an error

> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression
>   1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sampleCart.p.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I checked with just image table and product table ,GROUP_CONCAT was working with linking these 2 tables . but this is happening after linking more than 2 tables .

QUERY WITH OUT GROUP_CONCAT

```
select p.id,p.name as entityName,
      pi.name,
      pi.description,
      pi.language,
      im.image,
      ci.name as categoryname
 from products p,
 productInformation pi,
 product_attributes pa,
 images im,
 categoryInformation ci,
 categories c 
 where ci.category=c.id
 and ci.language='en'
 and c.id = p.category and p.category in (1,2)
 and im.entityid=p.id and im.type='product' and pi.language='en'
 and pi.productid=p.id and pa.attributevalueid in (2)
 and p.id=pa.productid and p.name like '%p%' and p.price between 0 and 15  ;
```

RESULT WITH OUT GROUP_CONCAT

```
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------+
| id | name | price | category | id | productid | name | description   | language | image       |
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------+
| 1  | pen  |    10 |        2 |  1 |         1 | pen  | this is a pen | en       | 12939.jpg   |    
| 1  | pen  |    10 |        2 |  1 |         1 | pen  | this is a pen | en       | 2932929.jpg |
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------+
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | name | price | category | id | productid | name | description   | language | image                              |
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | pen  |    10 |        2 |  1 |         1 | pen  | this is a pen | en       | 12939.jpg;2983.jpg;30940.jpg       |
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Please help . 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: As you have written it, your call to `GROUP_CONCAT` is telling MySQL to apply a function to the _entire_ table.  It therefore makes no sense to also select individual columns.  Please show us your expected output.

Comment: Yes just add a group by a the end of your query

Comment: @DanielE. Tried it not working ..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Results needed is 
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------+
| id | name | price | category | id | productid | name | description   | language | image       |
+----+------+-------+----------+----+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | pen  |    10 |        2 |  1 |         1 | pen  | this is a pen | en       | 12939.jpg;2938.jpg;293892.jpg   |

Comment: Add the result in your question, better than in comment

Comment: what if you specify your group by field. Eg: `group by im.entityid, im.type`

Comment: @DanielE. Thanks , Question edited .

Comment: @4givN Tried it , Not working ..

Comment: then `group by p.id,
    p.name, 
    pi.name,
    pi.description,
    pi.language,ci.name`

Comment: @4givN Good job Man it works now .. Thanks a Lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There is few problem in your question :

1- To join the tables it's better to use Inner Join or Left Join like this :

```
SELECT p.id,
  p.name as entityName,
  pi.name,
  pi.description,
  pi.language,
  im.image,
  ci.name as categoryname
FROM products p
INNER JOIN productInformation pi ON pi.productid=p.id
INNER JOIN images im ON im.entityid=p.id
INNER JOIN categories c  ON c.id = p.category 
INNER JOIN categoryInformation ci ON ci.category=c.id
WHERE ci.language='en'
   and  p.category in (1,2)
   im.type='product' and pi.language='en'
   pa.attributevalueid in (2)
   p.name like '%p%' and p.price between 0 and 15
```

It's more "readable" in my opinion and you are following the SQL recommendation.

2- In your output and the expected result, you are not using the same columns in the select
    So I won't take care of your output and just according to your query :

```
SELECT p.id,p.name as entityName,
  pi.name,
  pi.description,
  pi.language,
  GROUP_CONCAT(im.image, ";"),
  ci.name as categoryname
FROM products p
INNER JOIN productInformation pi ON pi.productid=p.id
INNER JOIN images im ON im.entityid=p.id
INNER JOIN categories c  ON c.id = p.category 
INNER JOIN categoryInformation ci ON ci.category=c.id
WHERE ci.language='en'
   and  p.category in (1,2)
   im.type='product' and pi.language='en'
   pa.attributevalueid in (2)
   p.name like '%p%' and p.price between 0 and 15
GROUP BY p.id,
      entityName,
      pi.name,
      pi.description,
      pi.language,
      categoryname
```

Comment: Thank you . i will try to implement this way in future .

Comment: In the future try to be more precise than "it's not working" in your comment ;)

Comment: E .. Sure i will be more precise :D

Answer (score 0):

@4givN Query is fixed now 
Updated Query

select p.id,p.name as entityName,pi.description,pi.language,GROUP_CONCAT(im.image SEPARATOR ';') as images,ci.name as categoryname from products p,productInformation pi,product_attributes pa,images im,categoryInformation ci,categories c where ci.category=c.id and ci.language='en' and c.id = p.category and p.category in (1,2) and im.entityid=p.id and im.type='product' and pi.language='en' and pi.productid=p.id and pa.attributevalueid in (2) and p.id=pa.productid and p.name like '%p%' and p.price between 0 and 15 group by p.id, p.name, pi.name, pi.description, pi.language,ci.name;

RESULT 
+----+------------+---------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| id | entityName | description   | language | images       | categoryname |
+----+------------+---------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | pen        | this is a pen | en       | 12.jpg;2.jpg | laptops      |
+----+------------+---------------+----------+-----------------------+-----+